# Launching a background process in current Powershell session

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a method to launch a background process in Powershell.  At first I tried using Start-Job and then realized that that launches the job in a new session. My end goal is to create a while loop that runs every hour (already have that code worked out) but I can't find a way to launch it in a background process that once the session closes the process with stop as well.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "My end goal is to create a while loop that runs every hour" have you heard of... scheduled tasks? :)

Comment: I have, but to my understanding a scheduled task in Windows is for the whole user not just the life of a Powershell session.  As in you open a Powershell window the task starts and once the window is closed the task stops. Am I incorrect in this?